# How to add text and Inline buttons in switch_inline_query button?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I have a Inline button with attribute switch_inline_query, and I want after pressing the button and choosing conversation from bot sent a message in inline mode with the text and inline buttons, how can I make it? Please any ideas.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I’ve got invite link, user can push the button (type switch_inline_query) and choose conversation, the person to whom such an invitation was sent should receive the message in an inlane mode which includes the text and inline buttons. Now bot can send only a simple text not in inline mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reply_markup` in result, just like [this example](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?answerInlineQuery-d0405f8d)